# Navigation drawer listview doesn't show first element of array

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

**Update**: I think the problem may be that the `ListView` is starting too high, and thus the first element of the list view exists but is not shown on the screen. I know the first element exists, but it simply is not shown. I have been experimenting with `RecyclerView` and I just got the a similar problem: the first element of the `RecyclerView` started too high, and half of it was cut off. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

I've made a navigation drawer largely similar to the one found on Google's [developer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) pages. The problem is that the drawer will not show the 0 element of the array I am using- it will only show elements 1 and 2.

Please see the relevant code below. I'm running Android 5.0.1 and just in case it matters, my theme is `Material.Light.DarkActionBar`.

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Thank you!

`MainActivity`:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close)
    {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {...}

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {...}
    };
}

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.leftDrawer);

    //NavDrawerItem is just a simple class with only a constructor to assign the int and String
    NavDrawerItem [] navDrawerItems = new NavDrawerItem[3];

    //NAVIGATION DRAWER ONLY SHOWS "ARCHIVE" AND "GALLERY"
    navDrawerItems[0] = new NavDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_menu_home, "Home");
    navDrawerItems[1] = new NavDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_menu_archive, "Archive");
    navDrawerItems[2] = new NavDrawerItem(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, "Gallery");

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, navDrawerItems));
```

`NavDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavDrawerItem>`:

```
private final Context context;
private final int layoutResourceId;
private NavDrawerItem data[] = null;

public NavDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, NavDrawerItem [] data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

    View v = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerImageView);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerTextView);

    NavDrawerItem choice = data[position];

    imageView.setImageResource(choice.icon);
    textView.setText(choice.name);

    return v;
}
```

`drawerLayout.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#eeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`drawer_list_item.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>

    <ImageView
        ...>

    <TextView
        ...>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Put `Log.e("position", "" + position);` in your `getView` and look if position is 0 at anytime.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, all three positions were logged, but only the last two appeared in the navigation drawer. I hesitate to say this, but I think it *might* have something to do with the recent update to Android 5.0.1. This code has been unchanged since 4.x, and it only started misbehaving after the upgrade from 5.0.0 to 5.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried `getActionBar().hide()` ? In some window modes the action bar can overlay your content.